# AngularJS ng-dialog not working with Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, jquery-select2

I have Angular dialog and I am using Select2 as a plug-in for my dropdowns. Now, the select2 plugin is working well in some pages but not when I use ng-dialog.

```
$('.select2').select2();

<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control">
  <option></option>
  <option>Canada</option>
  <option>Mexico</option>
  <option>United States</option>
</select>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/XLdB6RKwAWlPkj7MGH6M?p=preview

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this would be through the angular directive for select2. Which has been replaced by https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select. You should have less issues with angular by using the directive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that span field in select2 doesn't appear because "z-index" property in ngDialog css file, at .ngdialog class. You simply adjust his level to select2 works correctly.